# Resolving a view that is outside the application container

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm building a Java Spring app, and I'm working around a few constraints in the production environment, due to the fact that content is being published from a CMS. I have my images, js, css and jsp views residing in a static folder. I'm running a Tomcat app server, and i've set up Virtual directory mappings in the server.xml to map the images, css and js, which is working:

```
<Context debug="1" docBase="/home/content/images" path="/images" reloadable="true"/>
<Context debug="1" docBase="/home/content/css" path="/css" reloadable="true"/>
<Context debug="1" docBase="/home/content/js" path="/js" reloadable="true"/>
<Context debug="1" docBase="/home/content/view" path="/view" reloadable="true"/>
```

I've run into a problem resolving my jsp views, though. I'm using a Spring URIBasedViewResolver, configured as below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

The views aren't being found and I am getting 404 errors. Is it possible to resolve views outside the container? All of the examples and tutorials I can find have the views located within the /WEB-INF folder.

Thanks in advance! 
Kate

Comment: What do you mean "outside the container"? Where are they?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be, but for the life of me I cannot remember how. You will probably need to use either a different view resolver or write a custom one. It should not be too hard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using the InternalResourceViewResolver in addition to a JSP polling scheduler to pull JSPs from the file system into the WEB-INF folder.